# Using DateTime Parameters in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, datetime, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Essentially I'm trying to build a date picker filter for my List page. I started by using some of the logic found in the search function detailed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-paging

My Get method is structured like so:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageIndex, string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            if (endDate==null)
            {
                endDate = TimeUtils.DateToString(DateTime.Now);
            }
            if (startDate==null)
            {
                startDate = TimeUtils.DateToString(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60));
            }
            EndDate = TimeUtils.StringToDate(endDate);
            StartDate = TimeUtils.StringToDate(startDate);
            CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            DateSort = sortOrder == "Date" ? "" : "Date";
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            CurrentFilter = searchString;
            IQueryable<Issue> issuesIQ = _context.Issue.Include(o => o.Agent);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                issuesIQ = issuesIQ.Where(o => o.Agent.ADAccount.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    issuesIQ = issuesIQ.OrderByDescending(o => o.Agent.ADAccount);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    issuesIQ = issuesIQ.OrderBy(o => o.ContactDate);
                    break;
                case "Name":
                    issuesIQ = issuesIQ.OrderBy(o => o.Agent.ADAccount);
                    break;
                default:
                    issuesIQ = issuesIQ.OrderByDescending(o => o.ContactDate);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 50;
            Issues = await PaginatedList<Issue>.CreateAsync(issuesIQ.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex ?? 1, pageSize);
            
            
        }
```

This sets the date range to the last 60 days when I initially load the page(when no parameters are supplied) and converts them to strings(more on that in a moment), then converts whatever is stored in those strings into the DateTime objects used by the Picker(shown below)

```
<form asp-page="./Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label asp-for="EndDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>Find by Agent NT:
            <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@Model.CurrentFilter" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" /> |
            <a asp-page="./Index">Back to full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

From there, I modify the next and previous buttons to pass the value of the picker(after converting it back to a string) to the get method when navigating from page to page.

```
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Issues.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter"
   asp-route-endDate="@TimeUtils.DateToString(Model.EndDate)"
   asp-route-startDate="@TimeUtils.DateToString(Model.StartDate)"
   class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-page="./Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.CurrentSort"
   asp-route-pageIndex="@(Model.Issues.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@Model.CurrentFilter"
   asp-route-endDate="@TimeUtils.DateToString(Model.EndDate)"
   asp-route-startDate="@TimeUtils.DateToString(Model.StartDate)"
   class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

Now, to explain why I'm using strings for the parameters and where I'm stuck. I noticed when I was initially using DateTimes as the parameters I'd have them default to DateTime.MinValue, which wasn't a huge thing to overcome, but when I would navigate to the next page my URL would have a bunch of gibberish and my picker values would simply read mm/dd/yyyy. I did some reading and found IIS doesn't like to play well with some of the delimiters in DateTime, even with the [DataType(DataType.Date)] annotations I had in play. At this point I read some documentation on DateTime.Parse and DateTime.ToString and made these helper functions in TimeUtils

```
public static DateTime StringToDate(string datetime)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(datetime);
            return dt;
        }
        public static string DateToString(DateTime dt)
        {
            return dt.ToString("d");
        }
```

This should just convert the DateTime to a string like 9/15/2020, but when I try to navigate from page to page I'm getting the following at the end of my URL:

**/Issues?pageIndex=3&endDate=9%2F14%2F2020&startDate=7%2F16%2F2020**

To boil all this down, am I on the right path here and do I just need to do additional customization on the Parse and ToString functions to eliminate those "/"s from the strings? I'm considering using de culture as an argument in the ToString call to convert it to ".", but not sure if I'll run into similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by continuing down the path I was on, but with a few caveats I'm still scratching my head on. Updated the TimeUtils helper functions as follows:

```
public static DateTime StringToDate(string datetime)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime,"yyyy-MM-dd",null);
            return dt;
        }
        public static string DateToString(DateTime dt)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(dt.Year);
            sb.Append("-");
            if (dt.Month < 10)
                sb.Append("0");
            sb.Append(dt.Month);
            sb.Append("-");
            if (dt.Day < 10)
                sb.Append("0");
            sb.Append(dt.Day);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

I initially went the route of "yyyyMMdd" format, but when I tried to do the initial filter(clicking search) I had an error indicating the ParseExact couldn't convert "2020-09-16" to a valid date. I couldn't find anywhere in the OnGet this conversion was occurring and figured something wonky was happening with Append, so I updated the ParseExact to the new format. This worked fine until I went to the next page, which actually followed my DateToString as initially coded(without the "-"s) and failed. I updated the DateToString to include the "-"s and now everything works as intended. My guess is some kind of implicit conversion to "yyyy-MM-dd" was happening on the asp-for selection in the filter? Regardless it works.

What a ride.